# Export central coordinates of current map in print layout

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am trying to export the centrum coordinates of the current map in the print layout, and show the coordinates as a text element.

I have succeeded to print the centrum coordinates of a geometry in the in the map when using the atlas tool, i.e. `x( @atlas_geometry )`, and  `y( @atlas_geometry )`. The result shows like the image below.

[image]

But I would like to print the center coordinates of the current map, without having to use the atlas tool. I guess I will have to change the `@atlas_geometry` to something similar to `map_get()`, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the following statement, assuming that you map in the mapcomposer has the id: map1. the example below gives you the x coordinate

```
x(map_get(item_variables('map1'), 'map_extent_center'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It worked perfectly!